# How do I get privacy permissions to reappear after it has been initially rejected?

Tags: ios, swift

`Privacy-Speech recogition alert message.`
`Privacy-Microphone usage alert message.`

Both require access to the microphone but once it's rejected it will not reappear, therefore the user will never be able to use the function.

As soon as you tap on the record button you are prompted with an alert.

Tested it on my own devices, tried just about everything I can think of.

```
SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate

let recordButton = RecordButton()
let speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer? = SFSpeechRecognizer()
let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?

func recordAndRecognizeSpeech() {

    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) {
            buffer, _ in self.request.append(buffer)
        }
        audioEngine.prepare()
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            return print(error)
        }
        guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
            else { return }
        if !myRecognizer.isAvailable { return }
        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { result, error in 
                if let result = result {
                    let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString

                    self.textView.text = bestString
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
        })
    }
    @objc func recordButtonTap() {
        self.recordAndRecognizeSpeech()
    }
```

Has anybody ever had to deal with this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the status of the permission and if its `.denied` ask user with some alert you created and open settings for user if needed:

```
func askForMicPermission() {
    switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {
    case .granted:
        print("Permission granted")
        // grantedAction()

    case .denied:
        print("Pemission denied")

        // Show alert to user and ask them to turn it on from settings

        // Open settings
        let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else { return assertionFailure("Settings not found") }
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        }

    case .undetermined:
        print("Request permission here")

        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
            // granted ? grantedAction() : deniedAction()
        })
    }
}
```

Don't forget to `import AVFoundation`

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to select it as answer and upvote if it is helpful.